# Read the Description of a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm using `C:\Windows\System32\sc.exe` (via `System.Diagnostics.Process`) to create several Windows services via a custom install wizard I've built.  Each service created will contain a program with one or more modules loaded (chosen by the user via the wizard).

When this wizard is loaded I want to be able to inform the user of what services with which modules are currently installed.  I have used the service description (`sc description "....."`) to write which modules are part of each service.

However, I cannot find a method to read a service's description programmatically.  I find it surprising that it's not part of `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController`

Is there a way to read a service's description via C#?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

public static string GetServiceDescription(string serviceName)
{
    using (ManagementObject service = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(string.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", serviceName))))
    {
        return service["Description"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all the services returns description in ManagementObject, so it's better to use try catch...

```
    string cDescription = "";
    ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
    foreach(var serviceItem in services)
    {
        ManagementObject serviceObject = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(string.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", serviceItem.ServiceName)));
        try
        {
            cDescription = serviceObject["Description"].ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            cDescription = ex.Message; // or just leave it empty!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example; `System.Management` and `System.ServiceProcess` references required:

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.ServiceProcess;

var services = ServiceController.GetServices();
foreach (var service in services)
    using (var serviceObject = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(string.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", service.ServiceName))))
        Console.WriteLine($"{service.ServiceName} - {serviceObject["Description"]?.ToString()}..");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `QueryServiceConfig2` Win32 API to get the Windows service description. This method is far more fast compared to the WMI solution.

[image]

1. Specify the service name.
2. Get the SCM database handle using the `OpenSCManager` Win32 method.
3. Open the service handle using `OpenService` Win32 API, specifying the service name and SCM handle.
4. Call the `QueryServiceConfig2` with empty buffer, the `pcbBytesNeeded` parameter receives the needed buffer size.
5. Allocate the buffer with the required size using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`.
6. Call `QueryServiceConfig2` again with the allocated buffer and buffer size.
7. Convert the buffer to `SERVICE_DESCRIPTION` structure.
8. Free the buffer and close the all the open handles.

   ```
       using System;
       using System.Diagnostics;
       using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

       namespace Test
       {
       internal class Program
       {

       #region "Constants"

       const uint ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;

       const uint SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG = 0x0001;
       const uint STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;
       const uint SC_MANAGER_CONNECT = 0x0001;
       const uint SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE = 0x0002;
       const uint SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE = 0x0004;
       const uint SC_MANAGER_LOCK = 0x0008;
       const uint SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS = 0x0010;
       const uint SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG = 0x0020;
       const uint SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS = STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SC_MANAGER_CONNECT | SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_LOCK | SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS | SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG;

       #endregion

       #region "Win32 APIs"

       [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
       static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string lpMachineName, string lpDatabaseName, uint dwDesiredAccess);

       [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
       static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, uint dwDesiredAccess);

       [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
       static extern bool QueryServiceConfig2(IntPtr hService, SERVICE_CONFIG dwInfoLevel, IntPtr lpBuffer, uint cbBufSize, out uint pcbBytesNeeded);

       [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
       static extern bool CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr hSCObject);

       #endregion

       #region "Enumerations"

       public enum SERVICE_CONFIG : uint
       {
           SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION = 1,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS = 2,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO = 3,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS_FLAG = 4,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_SERVICE_SID_INFO = 5,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_REQUIRED_PRIVILEGES_INFO = 6,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_PRESHUTDOWN_INFO = 7,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_TRIGGER_INFO = 8,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_PREFERRED_NODE = 9,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_LAUNCH_PROTECTED = 12
       }

       #endregion

       #region "Structures"

       [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
       public struct SERVICE_DESCRIPTION
       {
           public string lpDescription;
       }

       #endregion

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {

           Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
           stopwatch.Start();

           string svcName = "Power"; // Change this to the service name you want to get its description

           // Get the SCM database handle
           IntPtr schSCManager = OpenSCManager(null, null, SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG);

           // Get the service handle

           IntPtr schService = OpenService(schSCManager, svcName, SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG);
           if (schService == IntPtr.Zero)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Win32 API OpenService failed ({0})", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
               return;
           }

           // Query the service description
           IntPtr buffer;

           bool success = QueryServiceConfig2(schService, SERVICE_CONFIG.SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out uint bytesNeeded);

           if (!success && Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
           {

               buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)bytesNeeded);
               bool success2 = QueryServiceConfig2(schService, SERVICE_CONFIG.SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION, buffer, bytesNeeded, out bytesNeeded);

               if (!success2)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Win32 API QueryServiceConfig2 failed ({0})", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                   return;
               }

           }
           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Win32 API QueryServiceConfig2 failed ({0})", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
               return;
           }

           // Read the description from the buffer
           SERVICE_DESCRIPTION description = (SERVICE_DESCRIPTION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(SERVICE_DESCRIPTION));
           Console.WriteLine("{0} service description: {1}", svcName, description.lpDescription);

           // Free the buffer and close the handles
           Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
           CloseServiceHandle(schService);
           CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);

           stopwatch.Stop();
           Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time: {0} Milliseconds", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

           Console.ReadLine();

       }

   }
   ```

   }

**References:**

[OpenSCManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-openscmanagerw)

[OpenService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-openservicew)

[QueryServiceConfig2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-queryserviceconfig2w)